# PHPExcel XLS output compatability with Excel 2000

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel, xls

I am designing a few scripts to write Excel files from MySQL stored data.

Unfortunately I need to design it for use for a company wide intranet and the down-side is some of the systems are runnin Citrix with Office 2000 (yep that's right Excel 2000)

I am using the PHPExcel package and it is writing the files great, but they just open as jumbled chars in 2000.

I am currently using Excel5 output as I thought that would have better compatability

> $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel); 
>   $objWriter->save($excelOutputFile);

I know the solutions really should be to upgrade the stupid old obsolete Citrix systems... or to export to CSV files instead of Excel but these are the paramaters for the project and the finance team aren't the greatest people to try and negotiate with.  So I would like to try and find a solution in PHP for the current systems if possible.

Anyone have any recommendations or pointers?

Comment: Do they open successfully in some other versions of Excel?

Comment: Yeah it opens perfectly in 2007.  I am pushing for them to just upgrade the cruddy old machines to avoid the issue.

Comment: By *jumbled chars* you mean that only text is corrupted, or file is totally unreadable by Excel 2000?

Comment: totally unreadable, like when you open a binary file in notepad or the like.

Comment: Can you share some example file?

Comment: The file itself has sales and payroll data so can't share any contents of the xls file, did you want any of the php file?

Comment: Excel5 written files should open cleanly in Excel2000. It's most likely that somewhere in the file there is some corruption caused by an output from echoed characters or similar. Open the file in a text editor, and see if you have any leading or trailing white space characters, or any obvious PHP texts such as errors visible in the files. If you, can you please provide a sanitized output and sample script from on the codeplex forums so we can investigate.

Comment: @elzaer any generated file which can't be opened cleanly by Excel 2000, but opens successfully with Excel 2007.

Comment: @MarkBaker you were exactly right.  I was outputting a ghost sheet by the look of it that was corrupting the file, 2007 obviously was able to overlook and load it still, but after fixing it Excel5 Writer opens fine in 2000.  Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not opposed to switching to a different library, assuming it has the features you need, [this one (CSVtoXLS)](http://performantsystems.com/CSVtoXLS.html) is supposedly tested on Excel 2000. It looks like a straight up converter from csv to xls files, but it might be a good starting point.

Comment: This is a good start, I might have to re-write some of the library functions to fit the specific purpose but it certainly is better than installing the entire PEAR package just for the Excel functionality

Comment: basic test came back okay, so this looks to be the way to go until I can get the systems upgraded